# How to pass form_class data into model objects create in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I want to create article form in Django. The code below getting Error `FileModel.post" must be a "Article" instance`. because i want to create multiple file related article instances which is coming from forgnekey. i need to pass example `post=form.instances` when i submit form data but i don't understand how can i pass `FileModel.objects.create(post=self.form_class, file=f)`? I would be grateful for any help.

**views.py**

```
class CreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = FileForm
    template_name = 'create.html'
    success_url = '/'
    success_message = "New story has been created successfully"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        for f in self.request.FILES.getlist('file'):
            FileModel.objects.create(post=self.form_class, file=f) # Error is here!
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the instance created by the form, rather than just the form class. For example:

```
FileModel.objects.create(post=form.instance, file=f)
```

**Update:** As the Article hasn't been saved yet, when you try to attach it to the FileModel object, it won't let you.

Try something like this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    post = form.save(commit=False)
    post.author = self.request.user
    post.save()
    for f in self.request.FILES.getlist('file'):
        FileModel.objects.create(post=post, file=f)
    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: yes Dear also try this but i'm getting Error `save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'post'.
`

Comment: Ahh, I think I know why. I'll update my answer.